# Vector of std::function with variable Number of Arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I want to store `event_handler` into std::vector, then I will store  a `std::vector` into a `map` According to the map key I will call `listeners[index].handler_(args...)` with different arguments.

I realise the above isn't possible, because std::vector can not store different types; but I wonder if there are any alternatives I should consider.

```
template<class... Args>
using Handler = std::function<void(Args &&... args)>;

template<typename T>
struct event_handler  {
    event_handler(Handler<T> handler, bool once) : handler_(std::move(handler)), once_(once) {}

    Handler<T> handler_;
    bool once_;
};

std::vector<event_handler> listeners; // I known this line is wrong, here is just for example
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208092/discussion-on-question-by-langyu-vector-of-stdfunction-with-variable-number-of).

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate the values that you want to pass to the event handling functions from your `event_handler` (maybe none/zero) and those that the application/user of the `event_handler` want to pass.

The former you define as parameters in your `std::function` type, this list of parameters must of course be the same for all functions.
The latter are bound to the function calls when the function is passed to your event handler, using `std::bind()`.

Be aware that this solution bears the risk that a user of your library binds pointers or references to variables/objects that don't exist anymore when the handler is executed.